# standard deviation and mode

Tags: php

I have a  system that monitors the performance of students.  It tabulates the number of students who gained a score of 1,1.25,1.5,....5 (this is our grading system).  For example:

```
grading system     number of students
1                  12
1.25               10
1.5                15
1.75               15
2                  20
2.25               1
2.5                5
2.75               6
3                  8
5                  0
```

From this example, I need my system to determine which is the mode and then print it.  I also need to get the standard deviation.

I need this in PHP.  Can anyone help me with this?
Your ideas, comments, and suggestions are appreciated.

#### Update:

Here's what I've done so far:

Finished the standard deviation...but there are still discrepancies i can't resolve...when i calculate the standard deviation manually..the answer is different from the output of my system.. >.<

While for the mode I used an array..this is my code:

```
$sample = array($one[$ctr],$two[$ctr],$three[$ctr],$four[$ctr],$five[$ctr],$six[$ctr],$seven[$ctr],$eight[$ctr],$nine[$ctr],$ten[$ctr],$fda[$ctr]);

         rsort($sample);
         $holder = $sample[0];
     //$holder = $mode;
```

The sorting is successful and I can the highest number but I need to print the value of `$holder` to a table using fpdf.

Any ideas, why the value is not visible in the output?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the mode is easy. Just find the grade (2) which has the highest number of students (20) and there you are.

If there's more than one, then it's multi-modal and you should probably allow for that.

For the standard deviation, the method can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation). It's basically working out the mean of all those numbers (let's simplify this by using 1, 1, 2 and 7):

```
1 + 1 + 2 + 7     10
-------------  =  --  = 2.5
      4            4
```

then calculating the square root of the variance of all those samples from that mean:

```
    _____________________________________________
   / (1-2.5)^2 + (1-2.5)^2 + (2-2.5)^2 + (7-2.5)^2
  /  ---------------------------------------------
\/                         4

       __________________________
      / 2.25 + 2.25 + 0.25 + 20.25
=    /  --------------------------
   \/               4

=  2.5
```

---

If you're asking a beginner-level question like how best to do this in a specific language like PHP, you should investigate the use of [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

Comment: so...will i use a lot of "if statements"...?hahahahah...i really have no idea how to deal with the moed...hahahha...

Comment: @arianne lee - A lot of `if()` statements or a single `for()` loop, to your liking. Is this homework?

Comment: Oh, +1 for the ASCII-art math alone... =D